# How to propagate FlashMap attributes using Springs RedirectStrategy?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, flash-message

I want to add some FlashMessages to the request/response cycle.

Since I add these attributes not within a Controller, but inside an AuthenticationFailureHandler, I cannot rely on the usual redirect attribute helper. Therefore I use RequestContextUtils to get the outputFlashMap and add the parameter I want. However, I can't access them in Thymeleaf, neither by using `${#request.getAttribute('message')}` nor directly by using the key itself `${message}`.

The handler class looks like this:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {

    private final RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException {

        FlashMap outputFlashMap = RequestContextUtils.getOutputFlashMap(request);
        outputFlashMap.addTargetRequestParam("message", "Elvis says Aloha from Hawaii");

        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "/secrets");
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: This will only get the flashmap, as the request isn't handled by the `DispatcherServlet` the `FlashMap` won't get stored in the session and thus not restored afterwards.

Comment: So how do I do it, to get the DispatcherServlet handle the request?

Comment: The problem is you are trying to use something that is for the `DispatcherServlet` and controllers from within a `Filter`. So unless you will move that out of `DispatcherServlet` into a `Filter` which executes before the security chain, this won't work.

Comment: @M.Deinum: I've succeeded with using a newly created FlashMap and saved it by a SessionFlashMapManager like this: `FlashMap outputFlashMap = new FlashMap(); outputFlashMap.put("identifier", "Franz Ferdinand"); new SessionFlashMapManager().saveOutputFlashMap(outputFlashMap, request, response);` Is this approach acceptable, or am I missing something? According to Spring's documentation, the FlashMap will be automatically deleted, so there shouldn't be a memory leak.

Comment: Until there is another `FlashMapManager` in use. You probably should autowire the `FlashMapManager` instead of creating a new one.